# How do i select a coma seperated list of values into a single column

Tags: oracle

I have a string of comma separated values "'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'".

```
select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' from dual;
```

How do i select these into a temp table all in a single column rather than a column per value?  So my select would return output like this:

```
value
a
b
c
d
```

Note: Doing the normal multiple selects and unions is not allowed due to the comma separated values as the input.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this, taking the assumption that you can qualify your columns:

```
SQL> select val from
   ( select 'a' as c1, 'b' as c2, 'c' as c3, 'd' as c4 from dual ) unpivot include 
     nulls ( val for col in ( c1,c2,c3,c4 ) );

V
-
a
b
c
d
```

In this option, it does not matter what values you have in 'a' , 'b' , 'c' 'd' , as basically unpivot is transposing columns into rows.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use hierarchy query as follows:

```
SQL> with YOUR_DATA as (select q'#'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'#' as str from dual)
  2  -- Your query starts from here
  3  SELECT TRIM('''' FROM TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL))) AS RESULT
  4    FROM YOUR_DATA CONNECT BY
  5  LEVEL <= 1 + REGEXP_COUNT(STR,',');

RESULT
------------------
a
b
c
d

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have version 12c or later, and if your data has no weird characters, then:

```
with input(x) as (select q'#'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'#' from dual)
select x_out from input,
json_table(
  '['||replace(x, '''', '"')||']', '$[*]'
  columns x_out path '$'
);

X_OUT
a
b
c
d
```